# Flutter refactor options are not showing in Visual Studio Code context menu

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Is there a specific option to set to enable the refactor context menu or something else which causes this?

Even with the shortcut there are not more options.

Missing some settings like 'Wrap With [...]' (see screenshots)

How it looks in one Project with the missing entries:

[image: project with missing options]

How it (should) look(s) in another project:

[image: on project on same MacBook]

Flutter doctor:

[image: flutter doctor]

Comment: Update or install Flutter/Dart plugins. Also, are you using an M1 mac? VS code insiders for M1 has lots of issues with Flutter.

Comment: no, it's an Intel Mac and as I mentioned, on another project, on the same Macbook/User the extended refactor menu is available. so I think it's not a problem of missing plugins. Same issue in Android Studio..
but anyway, good info with the M1 issues though

Answer (score 0):

If you install any extension you can remove it and test again. It worked for me.